# How to fix 'create_channel BAD REQUEST(status code : 400)' in Discord.py

Tags: discord.py

There was no problem with this code. But one day, suddenly, an error started to appear. Please help me. (I used the translator.) Thanks

I have no idea.. Sorry.

```py
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def test(ctx):
    server = ctx.message.server
    name = "NAME"

    await client.create_channel(server, "NAME", type=discord.ChannelType.voice)
```

This is error code.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ydepong93/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 50, in wrapped
    ret = yield from coro(args, **kwargs)
  File "feelblue.py", line 5790, in test
    await client.create_channel(server, name, type=discord.ChannelType.text)
  File "/home/ydepong93/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 2163, in create_channel
    data = yield from self.http.create_channel(server.id, name, str(type), permission_overwrites=perms)
  File "/home/ydepong93/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 200, in request
    raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: BAD REQUEST (status code: 400)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ydepong93/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 846, in process_commands
    yield from command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/ydepong93/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 374, in invoke
    yield from injected(ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/home/ydepong93/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 54, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(e) from e
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: HTTPException: BAD REQUEST (status code: 400)
```

Comment: What version of discord.py are you using?

Comment: I'm using 0.16.12 version

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=create_voice#discord.Guild.create_voice_channel

You must use

```
await ctx.guild.create_voice_channel(**kwargs)
```

Instead of your code. Next times better if you give the docs a look before asking here.